# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger into visual studio 2015

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I've a Xamarin Android app running on Visual Studio 2015. Since a few days I'm no longer able to edit XML layout files into Android Designer getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/utils/ILogger
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.utils.ILogger
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
Exception in thread "main"
```

I've already tried to update JAVA (to jdk 1.8) and setting it, update Xamarin to the lastest version and installed almost all missing Android SDK versions and tools.

Any idea on how to fix it to come back to edit & visualize Android xml/axml layout activities?

Comment: Aaargh! Just happened to me.. did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was fixed by removing the Preview Channel Packages and install the previous version packages.

Open Android SDK Manager and delete "Tools (Preview Channel) > Android SDK Tools". Install previous version Android SDK Platform Tools (in my case Rev 23.1)